# Error while validate or upload on App Store "The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken"

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, build, xcode8, archive

"The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken"

[image]

Comment: Getting error before upload. In above case it was uploaded and apple has send email with details to owner.

Comment: The error is clearly mentioning the problem. You have to create a new bundle id or use the one which is not being used to upload into Appstore.

Comment: Already created with new id, with new profile but still found similar issue.

Comment: Try uploading with "application loader app" instead of the organizer. You might also need to check the itunesconnect if the app you created is having correct bundle id

Comment: @Aslam Just for confirmation of issue. I have upload fresh single view project with same name and same bundle identifier, it was validate successful and processing done. but dose't work for actual project. Actually  IOS project generate by Unity OSX Mac Editor.

Comment: @Aslam Dose't work even in application loader, same error found.

Comment: Check your itunnesconnect name and bundle id if they are correct

Comment: I don't think on itunnesconnect name and bundle id has having any issue, because fresh app was already upload and processing successful. And app name on itunnesconnect validate by apple so can't duplicate ever, also display name is free to use, it dose't validate by apple.